# UITableView Indexing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, indexing

I have an indexed table view that organizes cities in a state by their first letter. What I have working is an NSMutableDictionary is created with the keys of A,B,C,etc. and the corresponding cities are added to their respective arrays. ex:

```
Y =     (
    Yatesboro,
    Yeagertown,
    York,
    "York Haven",
    "York New Salem",
    "York Springs",
    Youngstown,
    Youngsville,
    Youngwood,
    Yukon
);
Z =     (
    Zelienople,
    Zieglerville,
    "Zion Grove",
    Zionhill,
    Zionsville,
    Zullinger
);
```

now, my table view loads with the correct number of sections, and rows within the sections and the indexing control works fine with this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [cities count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if([searchArray count]==0)
        return @"";
    return [searchArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[cities objectForKey:[searchArray objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"clicked index : %i",index]);
    if (index == 0) {
        [tableView scrollRectToVisible:[[tableView tableHeaderView] bounds] animated:NO];
        return -1;
    }
    return index;
}
```

My issue is now populating the text of the table cell with the text for each section...Any thoughts on how I can grab this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets a parameter of type `NSIndexPath` passed which contains both the required row and section. See [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

With that being said, this might work in your particular case:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  NSString *letter = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  NSArray *city = [cities objectForKey:letter];
  cell.text = [city objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}
```

Not sure if I got it right (haven't tried on a compiler), but you may get the general idea by now :)

Comment: Worked like a charm man. Saved a major headache for me. Thanks!